# How to highlight text using string indexes in WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, wpf-controls, richtextbox

I'm working on a custom RichTextBox which highlights certain words typed in it.
*(more like highlight certain strings, because I intent to highlight strings that are not separated by spaces)*

I search for strings by loading the text to memory, and looking for a list of strings one by one, then applying formatting to them.

Issue is that, index I get from the plain text representation, doesn't necessarily point to the same position in the RichTextBox's content, when formatting is applied.

(First formatting is perfect. Any subsequent formatting starts to slip to the left. I assume this is because formatting adds certain elements to the documents which makes my indexes incorrect.)

Sample pseudo code for this is as follows.

```
// get the current text
var text = new TextRange(Document.ContentStart, Document.ContentEnd).Text;

// loop through and highlight
foreach (string entry in WhatToHighlightCollection)
{
    var currentText = text;
    var nextOccurance = currentText.IndexOf(suggestion); //This index is Unreliable !!!

    while (nextOccurance != -1)
    {
        // Get the offset from start. (There appears to be 2 characters in the 
        // beginning. I assume this is document and paragraph start tags ?? 
        // So add 2 to it.)
        int offsetFromStart = (text.Length) - (currentText.Length) + 2;

        var startPointer = Document.ContentStart.
             GetPositionAtOffset(offsetFromStart + nextOccurance, LogicalDirection.Forward);

        var endPointer = startPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(suggestion.Length, LogicalDirection.Forward);

        var textRange = new TextRange(startPointer, endPointer);
        textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));
        textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
        textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Segoe UI"));

        // Go to the next occurance.
        currentText = currentText.Substring(nextOccurance + suggestion.Length);
        nextOccurance = currentText.IndexOf(suggestion);
    }
}
```

**How do I map string indexes to rich text box content ?**

**NOTE:** I'm not worried about the performance of this at the moment, although any suggestions are always welcome, as currently I run this on every TextChanged event to highlight 'as the user type' and it's getting a bit sluggish.